# Insert tab character in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, alpine-linux

I'm writing a dockerfile and I'm having trouble inserting the TAB character from the Dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine
RUN cd /usr/local/bin
RUN wget https://www.noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
RUN cd no'\t'
RUN apk add make
RUN make
RUN make install
```

The docker build keeps failing on `RUN cd no'\t'`

Comment: The directory literally has a tab character in its name?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying to trigger the autocomplete feature to avoid hard coding the directory name in the script.

Comment: @cheryrico2 That's not how it works. The tab autocomplete is only in the interactive shell.

Comment: @AndyLester is there a way to accomplish that end goal?

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is.  You just want to `cd` to the first directory that begins with "no" and that directory isn't going to have a specific name at build time?

Comment: the file name changes due to versioning

Comment: Probably what you will need to do is have your process that builds the versioned directory also create a symlink to it.  `notable_directory` will point at `notable_directory_v14.4.2` and then you'll have `RUN cd notable_directory` in the dockerfile.

Comment: ... or if there's only one such directory, you could construct a wildcard that would expand to that (one) directory.